# How to check if a function has __attribute__ in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, clang

Is it possible to check whether a function has **attribute**

For example:

```
__attribute__((annotate("foo"))) void foo() {}
```

has attribute, so the program should say that foo() function has attribute and its annotation is "foo"

And suppose there is another function say,

```
void baz() {}
```

then the program should say that the function baz() has no attribute or just return null.

Comment: Hmmm, `__attribute__` is nothing mentioned in the c++ standard IIRC.

Comment: Remove the compiler-errors tag too if forcing a compiler error based on some condition is not what you want.

Comment: `__attribute__` is gcc specific (maybe clang too)

Comment: I believe `__attribute__((...))` is a gcc/g++ thing, and that they use attributes internally to carry information about functions and variables.  The compiler just exposes the system to programmers as well because it's a good way to manage information that's relevant to a particular back-end.  So you could do this by re-purposing a c++ lexical analyzer, or by getting intermediate access to g++ and then printing out any non-standard attributes (but I think _everything_ will have _some_ attributes, so you'll have to decide which ones you want to ignore.)

Comment: google-hacking leads me to believe that `__has_attribute__` is a thing but haven't seen a single use of it, nor any documentation whatsoever on it

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Then it's most probably not _a thing_, no matter of your presonal beliefs.

Comment: There is no standard way to do this.

Comment: Some attributes are part of function type (like ms_abi) and those can be checked for by sfinae. I'm currently also searching for a way how to check for other attributes which are not a part of function type (i.e. apply only to function definition)...